# Filtering AWS-Cognito users by role

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I've been looking all day for how to do this to now avail.

Let's say I have two users in my User Pool, John Admin and Jim User. I have a view controller that I want to be accessible to John Admin but not Jim User. The problem is that I don't know how to distinguish John and Jim in my app.

Is there a way to know that John Admin is in my admin groups/role but Jim is not?

edit:
Asking for user attributes gave me:

```
{"UserAttributes": [
  { "Name": "sub", "Value": "NUMBERS"},
  { "Name": "email_verified", "Value": "true"},
  { "Name": "phone_number_verified", "Value": "false"},
  { "Name": "phone_number", "Value": "NUMBERS"},
  { "Name": "email", "Value": "EMAIL"}],
 "Username": "johnadmin"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using attributes, because IdentityID didn't show the groups embedded in as I thought.

```
var pool: AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool?
var user: AWSCognitoIdentityUser?
```

And within my method of interest:

```
if let strongUser = self.user {
    strongUser.getDetails().continueOnSuccessWith { (task) -> AnyObject? in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            if let response:AWSCognitoIdentityUserGetDetailsResponse = task.result {
                for attr in response.userAttributes! {
                    if attr.name == "custom:privilege", attr.value == "admin" {
                        self.adminButton.isHidden = false
                        return
                     }
                 }
             }
              self.adminButton.isHidden = true
        })
        return nil
    }
} else {
    adminButton.isHidden = true
}
```

The downside is that while not logged in, no custom attributes can be written to by the app, so I used the AWS-CLI to promote users:

```
aws cognito-idp admin-update-user-attributes --user-pool-id <POOLID> --username <USERNAME> --user-attributes '{"Name":"custom:privilege","Value":"admin"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your User model should contain some property that will allow you to distinguish users by their roles.
E.g

```
struct User {
   var name = ""
   var role = "User" // you can use enum here or anything else you want
}
```

After user got logged in you should set this property to proper value.
Further before presenting view controller you should check this property and decide to show or not to show this view controller

Comment: The users have been assigned groups on the Cognito Console, but I can't seem to find the API to get which group I assigned it to in iOS

Comment: You should try to get user attributes
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-ios-sdk.html
check paragraph "Authenticated Example: Get User Attributes"

Comment: No luck with the attributes, they gave me no relevant information.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSCognitoIdentity.html

take a look to the method "– getCredentialsForIdentity:"

Comment: I think the answer was proposing that you use an attribute, probably a custom one, instead of using a group. That's a viable way to go if you need a literal check on the client, which you mentioned you do. With a custom attribute, you can set and get as he described.

Comment: @Evgeniy, the method looked promising, specially since I once found in some documentation where the access key would have the user groups appended but it doesn't, at least in iOS.

Comment: One other note - the groups a user is in are embedded in the id token.

Comment: Not in iOS it seems, only the user pool region, but I worked on a work around with custom attributes.